# Please advise for the statement query

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where:

```
column 1     column 2
1            1234
2            5678
3            9192
```

I want to relate if the value in column 1 = to value column 2 as a new column.

Please advise!

Comment: Can you add some more formatting to your question, so it's clearer for the readers to what you mean?

Comment: "I want to relate if the value in column 1 = to value column 2 as a new column." Can you please rephrase that sentence? It does not make sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: show your required output

Comment: the scenario is like this:

Comment: the scenario is like this:   what i means, if the value in column 1 is = 1 automatically it will be equal to column 2 = 1234 and i want to set as a new column 3.  if the value is = 2 from column 2 automatically it will be equal to column 2 = 5678 and i want to set as a new column 4. and so on.  kindly please advise

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if column1 and two Match then you can use the following:

```
Select column1, 
       column2, 
       case 
         when column1 = column2 then 
           'Match' 
         else 
           'No Match' 
       end as 'Matching' 
  from tableX
```